# Nested for loop (or possibly create a function)

Tags: r

I am doing some very basic plots for exploratory analyses, and have successfully created a for loop to do most of the work for me. I have 12 years of data, 5 different categories(Cat1-Cat5), and 3 different variables(Say X,Y,Z). The loops that I have done so far gives me the histogram of each of the variables by year (so X in year 1 - X in year 12 for example).

I partitioned my data in 2 ways - by category, and by year as follows:

```
Cat.1<-subset(data,Category==1) #Similar code for categories 2-5
categories<-list(Cat.1,Cat.2,Cat.3,Cat.4,Cat.5)

Year.1<-subset(data,Year==1)
years<-list(Year.1,Year.2, ... , Year.12)
```

Now, with the data partitioned this way I have set up loops:

```
for(i in (1:length(categories))
{
  store.data<-categories[[i]]
  hist(store.data$X)
}
```

What I would like to do is have an external loop that deals with the 3 variables:

```
variables<-list(X,Y,Z)

for(j in (1:length(variables))
{
  #insert above for loop here
}
```

The desired output would be the output of all of the histograms for each year and each variable. I realize that I can just add in lines to the original for loop:

```
 hist(store.data$Y)
 hist(store.data$Z)
```

But, eventually I will be running analyses (ANOVA, t-test, etc) on the data and I plan on having the same setup. By having the external loop that deals with which variable the internal loop works on, I should have much less code to write in theory.

Comment: This problem description is sort of confusing. Instead of explaining it in terms of the strategy you've been using to try to solve the problem, why don't you start by showing us what your data looks like (just a small, reproducible, representative example) and focus on what precisely you want for your output? Nested for loops is probably not the way to go about this: people are probably going to suggest you use the `apply` functions instead for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

This short solution gives you the histograms, but doesn't name them to inform you which histogram relate to which category. The histograms will be named by variable, and the order the histograms are generated will correspond to the numerical order of you categories. It doesn't look like you're labeling you're histograms in the code you posted, so this may not be a problem for you.

```
category = rep(1:5,20)
X = rnorm(100)
Y = rexp(100)
Z = rgamma(100,5)

require(data.table)
DT = data.table(category, X, Y, Z)

DT[,lapply(.SD, hist), by=category]
```

Comment: you may (not clear from OP) want to add `x11()` in there and maybe dump the output (or wrap it in `invisible`)